# How do I use lodash _.size to determine the amount of times a property appears on an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

I have an array of objects that I'm doing some calculations on using lodash. I'm trying to group my calculations based on the 'conversationSource'. The 'people' property comes in as a string on each object. The goal is to output the amount of times the people property appears per 'conversation source' such as **{conversationSource: reddit, person: 2}**

I am using _.size from lodash to accomplish this. The problem is that it works on initial page load, however it doesn't work as I add additional objects to the array. I'm wondering if there is a better method in lodash of doing this.

```
   get() {
            let convertedData = this.dataOverview
            console.log(convertedData);
            let newData =
            _(convertedData)
            .groupBy('conversationSource')
            .map((objs, key) => ({
                'conversationSource': key,
                'conversationCount': _.sumBy(objs, 'conversationCount'),
                'inter': _.sumBy(objs, 'inter'),
                'chance': _.sumBy(objs, 'chanceSent'),
                'person': _.size(objs, 'person'),
                'personId': _.map(objs, 'personId'),
                'leadsPercent': _.round((_.sumBy(objs, 'leadsSent') / _.sumBy(objs, 'intera') || 0) * 100)
                }))
                .value();
                // console.log(newData);

                return (this.convertedData = newData);
```

Comment: A function would be evaluated once unless you call it again. Changing the data the function operates on will not automatically re-run the function. You need some way to link the changes to the array with re-running the function.

Comment: You can accomplish what you are trying to do with lodash and RxJS Observables. Check out [combineLatest](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html)